# AWS S3 redirect rules for subfolders with 404 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404

Is there any possibility to make redirects in S3 like this?

```
domain/us/wrongurl.html redirect to this ➜ domain/us/404.html
domain/uk/wrongurl.html redirect to this ➜ domain/uk/404.html
domain/wrongurl.html redirect to this ➜ domain/404.html
```

The closest solution:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>US</KeyPrefixEquals>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>domain.name</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>US/404.html#</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: That's about it, although the matches should be case-sensitive, and (just to be pedantic) I'd put a trailing slash on `<KeyPrefixEquals>us/</KeyPrefixEquals>` to avoid inadvertently matching (e.g.) `example.com/users` which also has `us` (but not `us/`) as a prefix.  You may also need to test for code 403 depending on bucket config.  You're doing some kind of SPA, I take it (based on the `#` in the rewrite rule)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that you have setup static web hosting on your bucket, you can set up a bucket level error document.

[image]

But there is a caveat,

> When an error occurs, Amazon S3 returns an HTML error document. If you have configured your website with a custom error document, Amazon S3 returns that error document. However, when an error occurs, some browsers display their own error message, ignoring the error document Amazon S3 returns. For example, when an HTTP 404 Not Found error occurs, Chrome might display its own error ignoring the error document that Amazon S3 returns.

Comment: No way this answers the question. The question is about to conditional (subfolder) redirect.